# How to list/delete the unused functions of a Python Framework

Tags: python, debugging

Hey I am working on a project that has a web-frontend. I use Flask for that and it fits my needs really well. However, the client is really concerned about file size and wants me to cut off every "unnecessary" function of the frameworks that are in use.

It isn't many frameworks but obviously I don't use every single function of them.

Basically, what I am looking for is a kind of debugger that "watches" everything going on in my code while I use the web interface and then it flags all the functions in these python files that have been called so it lets me delete cut away the functions that I don't need.

I don't really know how to approach this and I think there is going to be some tool that does just that. The alternative would be to do as I described but manually, this would result in DAYS of work.

Comment: You really are not going to gain much with this approach, if 'file sizes' are a concern. Source code is measured in kilobytes, not megabytes.

Comment: You can use the [coverage package](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.4.1/), but this sounds like a huge waste of your time. You can't just delete functionality from frameworks for example; you'll only create a huge maintenance burden for yourself every time you need to upgrade your dependencies (to fix a security issue, for example).

Comment: You really need to go back to your client and clarify what they mean by being concerned about file size. I suspect they are talking about the amount of data the *browser* has to download to run the site. Keeping your Javascript, CSS and image resources efficient is indeed important in a web application. But cutting Python source code **won't do a thing** to move those metrics.

Comment: Try gathering the code coverage (google: python code coverage). That might hint which functions were called, which were not.

Comment: I know that it sounds insane but he's really talking about file size. Idk what leads him to the belief that this makes things easier but he's paying very well so I don't even think of arguing with him. Thanks for `coverage` keyword. Still not exactly what I am looking for but this will defo makes things easier!